# About decompositions of integers.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer. Into how many ways can I decompose $n$ as a sum $j_1+\ldots+j_r$ of $r$ non-negative integers $j_1, \ldots, j_r$?

Does this kind of thing have name? Is there a book where I can read about it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))?

Comment: Or compositions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)